# Multiple Interfaces in Single Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that needs to communicate more than one Action back to it's Activity. For example,

1. When a button is clicked, it needs to communicate the onClick back to the Activity.

2.When a user's login and password match, a boolean value is sent to the Activity notifying it to start an Intent.

My first question is, is this common where a Fragment needs to relay more that one type of Action back to the Activity? And secondly, how is this solved? Is the following a good way to do it...

I created a custom class, which extends Fragment and included the two interfaces that I need (One to pass the onClick back to the Activity and One to pass a boolean value):

```
public class CustomInterfaceFragment extends Fragment {

public OnClickedListener listener;
public LogInInterface loggedInListener;

static interface OnClickedListener{
    public void buttonClicked(View v);
}

static interface LogInInterface{
    public void userLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.listener = (OnClickedListener)activity;
    this.loggedInListener = (LogInInterface)activity;
}}
```

I then extended this custom class in my Fragment and used the appropriate methods where needed. This is the onClick method in the Fragment...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.register_button:{
            listener.buttonClicked(v);//***Pass onClick Back to Activity
            break;
        }
        case R.id.fragment_login_loginButton:{
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(userName.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user!=null){
                        boolean verified = user.getBoolean("emailVerified");
                        if(!verified){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Verify",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            ParseUser.logOut();
                        }else{
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            loggedInListener.userLoggedIn(true);//***Pass boolean Back to Activity
                        }
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally I implemented the custom fragment class and its interfaces in my Activity in order to retrieve the data.

Is this a reasonable way to solve this problem or am I missing something? The application seems to work fine. I just want to know what the best programming practice would be. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

all i can say is you can bring down this two interfaces to one like this below

```
public interface fragmentInteractions{
   public void OnClickedListener(View v);
   public void userLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn);
   ....
   ....

}
```

and i don't think the interface here needs to be static

Comment: And just implement this in the Fragment class instead of making a separate custom one?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Avinash Joshi's answer :

```
public interface CustomListener {
          void onButtonClicked();
          void onLoginResult( boolean isUserLoggedIn ); // You can pass User object via this method in case its required to do some operations
    }

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CustomListener {


      @Override
      public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstance ) {

             // Initialize UI elements
             // Initialize Fragment

      }

       @Override
       public void onButtonClicked() {
          //Action to be performed on button click
       }

       @Override
       public void onLoginResult( boolean isUserLoggedIn ) {
          if( isUserLoggedIn ) {
             //take user to dashboard or any other screen
             //Usually with the help of SupportFragmentManager

          }
          else {
             //Take user to signup screen with an optional toast message 
             //In case parameters like User name and password need not be entered by user again, you can access them as function parameters and  pass them to signupFragment via bundle
          }
       }
    }

    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

       CustomListener mCustomListener;

       @Override
       public void onAttach( Context context ) {
          super.onAttach( Context context );
          try {
              mCustomListner = (CustomListener) context;
          } catch ( ClassCastException e  {
               Log.e(TAG, "Activity must implement CustomListener")
          }

       }

       //Rest of Fragment initialization code here
    }
```

Here's a complete example :

http://www.truiton.com/2015/12/android-activity-fragment-communication/